# Wordpress WooCommerce: Trash/Delete Product Action

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the Woocommerce Plugin.
When a Product is trashed, I want to send a mail.

I tried this with several trash/delete post actions, that wordpress provides, but i can't get it to work.

This is what I have tried:

```php
function delete_notification($post_id)
{
    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $message = "Post ".$post_id." has been deleted.";
    $subject = "Deleted Post";
    $to = //my email address
    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
}

add_action('wp_trash_post ', 'delete_notification');
add_action('delete_post ', 'delete_notification');
add_action('before_delete_post', 'delete_notification');
add_action('publish_to_trash', 'delete_notification');
add_action('draft_to_trash',   'delete_notification');
```

What could be the reason this isn't working? Does Woocommerce use Actions, that are different from Wordpress ones? I couldn't find anything about that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the follows code in your active theme's functions.php -

```
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'notification_for_product', 99 );
add_action( 'delete_post', 'notification_for_product', 99 );
function notification_for_product( $post_id ){
    if( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'product' ) return;
    $to = 'sendto@yourmail.com';
    $subject = "Deleted Post";
    $body = "Product #".$post_id." has been deleted.";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}
```

Comment: Check your mail configuration or you can add small log in above function to be sure it's calling the functionality.